# How to change default MSMQ Time-To-Reach-Queue time?

Tags: msmq, nservicebus, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a problem with Time-To-Reach-Queue being too long in Microsoft Message Queuing on some servers running Windows Server 2008 R2 .

How can we change the default time on the servers from 4 days to a lower value?

Answer (score 0):

If the machine is part of a domain you can change that value in "Sites and Services".
If not, I don't think is possible!